# Visual Studio 2017 deploying all projects in solution when publishing to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-deployment-slots

Before adding an additional Publish profile in Visual Studio, everything worked great.  When I right-clicked on the relevant project and selected 'Publish', I was able to deploy just that single VS project to my Azure app service.
After adding a 2nd Publish profile which deploys to an additional app service Staging slot, right-clicking on the relevant project deploys all VS projects in the solution with either profile.

I found [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906790/asp-net-core-solution-publishing-wrong-project), but not sure where/how to make those changes or if it's the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided is talking about the MSBUILD args that are in VS project properties where you find build arguments.

[image]

Hope this helps.